# Limit of UPN in Active Directory Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-server-2013

What is limit of UPN suffix in windows server 2012?
And Limit is based on one organization unit (OU) or overall?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

> No hostname in an Active Directory forest can exceed 64 characters.

Long answer:

> The depth of a domain tree is limited by a maximum fully qualified domain name (FQDN) length for a host of 64 characters. This means that the host name and the domain name combined cannot exceed 64 characters, including the periods that separate each component of the name.

And that rule is applied globally not just in `organizational units`.

Comment: limit mean no. of UPN suffix in Active directory?

Comment: No. Limit of characters in a upn. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Review the customer added comments here.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/active-directory-maximum-limits-scalability(v=ws.10).aspx

But note: you can add 850-1000 UPN suffixes to each OU, but realize that you can't necessarily use those across a trust.